# Fractional reaction-diffusion with Caputo derivative

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

I'm interested in the following Cauchy problem for a linear diffusion equation
$$
\begin{cases}
{^C}\!D^{a}_tu(t,x) = \sigma\Delta u(t,x),\\
u(0)=u_0\in X.
\end{cases}
$$

where ${^C}\!D^{\sigma}_t$
denotes the Caputo fractional derivative of order $a\in (0,1)$, and $X$ is a Banach space.
   I wonder if there are any well-posedness results and characterizations of the $C_0$ semigroup and its properties. Any reference would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $L^2(\Omega)$, see

> K. Sakamoto and M. Yamamoto, Initial value/boundary value problems for fractional diffusion-wave equations and applications to some inverse problems, J. Math. Anal. Appl.,382 (2011), 426–447.

For a general theory in Banach spaces, see

> E. G. Bajlekova, Fractional evolution equations in Banach spaces, Thesis, Eindhoven, 2001.

Note that solutions to fractional evolution equations do not satisfy the semigroup property!